# Segmentation fault when using gtk_threads_add_timeout

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I have created a very simple gtk interface that displays the time. As such it will need to be updated frequently and after looking into the docs, gtk_threads_add_timeout seemed a logical method to facilitate this. I adapted the function "set_time" to work with the gtk function and ended up with the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

typedef struct
{
  GtkWidget *label;
} time_args;

static int set_time(void *args);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkLabel *time;
    time_args t_args;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, temp, NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window_main"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
    gtk_window_fullscreen(GTK_WINDOW(gtk_widget_get_toplevel(window)));

    time = GTK_LABEL(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "time"));
    t_args.label = GTK_WIDGET(time);
    set_time(&t_args);
    gdk_threads_add_timeout(1000, set_time, &t_args);

    g_object_unref(builder);

    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

void on_window_main_destroy()
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}

static int set_time(void *args) {
    time_args *data = (time_args *)args;
    time_t rawtime = time(&rawtime);
    struct tm *timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    char *timeout;
    int hour = timeinfo->tm_hour;

    if(hour > 12) {
        hour -= 12;
        sprintf(timeout, "%d:%02d %s", hour, timeinfo->tm_min, "PM");
    } else {
        sprintf(timeout, "%d:%02d %s", hour, timeinfo->tm_min, "AM");
    }

    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(data->label), timeout);

    return G_SOURCE_CONTINUE;
}
```

It compiles fine with no warnings and calling `set_time(&t_args)` works fine on the first call, at the first instance of `gdk_threads_add_timeout(1000, set_time, &t_args)` however I get a segmentation fault. Anyone have any similar issues or have a similar use case that was solved using a different method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reserve space for `timeout` before using `sprintf`:

In this line:

```
sprintf(timeout, "%d:%02d %s", hour, timeinfo->tm_min, "PM");
```

The size of the buffer should be large enough to contain the entire resulting string, but you are using an uninitialized `char *`

```
char *timeout;
```

shoulde be

```
char timeout[32]; // Some arbitrary size
```

Comment: Wow it was staring me right in the face, thanks David. Just out of intrigue, why did the first assignment work and only fail on the second attempt to sprintf when uninitialized?

Comment: You're welcome, maybe in the first assignment it was writing/overwriting on some valid area, I'm just guessing because you enter in undefined behaviour fields ... anything can happens ...

Comment: Note that with GLib you can do `char* timeout = g_strdup_printf("%d:%02d %s, ...);` which is generally harder to mess up in this way.